# Best Poker sites on net

Tags: texas-hold-em, online

I just want to ask which is the best online poker there is on the net.
I am currently on Zynga Poker on facebook.Can u please suggest any good poker sites for free

Answer (score 2):

You can see some of the top poker sites discussed in the link I provide. This should be a good starting point. Other than that, search within the forum for "best poker sites" or something similar and you should find a lot of useful information.

[Poker Rooms Comparison](https://poker.stackexchange.com/q/1061/88)